# ASP.NET VB.NET Basic Shopping Cart Function

Tags: asp.net

Just wondering the best way to go about this, I am building  a VB.NET Shopping Cart Technology, with the basic entities of - User Logging In -  Going Through Shopping Cart - Checkout of Shopping Cart - Displaying Items in Shopping Cart.

Is there anything there off the shelf (free) that I can just pick up out there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) you can download several free open source eCommerce solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several in C# but if you want vb.net there is [Kartris](http://Kartris.codeplex.com) which is free and open source